# What is the fastest way to swizzle channels in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I've heard that in OpenGL, changing the texture data format from GL_RGBA to GL_BGRA significantly improves pixel transfer performance. Now there are two ways to swizzle the texture data to suit this format:

One is to modify the fragment shader, so instead of `FragColor = texture(...)` , use

```
vec4 t = texture(...);
FragColor = vec4(t.b,t.g,t.r,t.a);
```

However, the red book introduces another method, which is to set the parameter `GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_RGBA` .

On my small test program, both methods work. But which of these give better performance? I observe that setting the parameter can be done after uploading the data. So is the second method equivalent to the first, done implicitly by the driver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither method of texture swizzling has anything to do with [*pixel transfer* performance](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Pixel_Transfer). Pixel transfers happen when you make calls like `glTex(Sub)Image`. How you read that data in your shader is irrelevant to the performance of those functions.

What you're being advised to do is provide pixel transfer functions with data that is in BGRA order. That means *you* are the one who needs to swizzle the data *on the CPU*. But really, the advice is to make sure your on-disk texture data is pre-swizzled for optimal transfer performance. If you can't control the format of your on-disk data, then its best to let the implementation swizzle the texture data itself rather than you writing code to do so.

Theirs is probably faster.